# Shows "String index out of range" when using a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that makes the first letter of every line in uppercase, but it is unable to execute past the 6th line `if l[0].islower():` . The `l[0]` works fine when it's outside the loop, but is always says "String Index out of range" when I put it back in the loop.

```
m = open(r"C:\Users\■■■■■■\Desktop\■■■■\other.txt","r", encoding = "utf-8") #Just blocking the text out

while True:
    l = m.readline()

    if l[0].islower():
        l.replace(l[0],l[0].upper())
        
    print(l)
    
    if not l:
        break
m.close()
```

Comment: Please share the contents of the input file too.

Comment: Why are you looping that way? Why not just `for line in m`? Anyway you should put the `if not l` right after reading `l`, not in the end

Comment: Also, doing `replace(l[0], ...)` will replace **all** occurrences of that letter, not just the first

Answer (score 1):

See [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.capitalize), its probably what you want.

Also you can iterate a file line by line much easier.

```
path = r"other.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the check at the beginning of the loop rather than the end because you go on to access `l[0]` even if `l` is `None`.

```py
while True:

    l = m.readline()
    if not l:
        break

    if l[0].islower():
        l.replace(l[0],l[0].upper())
        
    print(l)
    
m.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("content.txt", 'r') as file:

    while 1:
        content = file.readline()
        if not content:
            break

        print(content.capitalize())

print("Done !")
```

you can use this.